# responsive navbar using display:none still shows even it is meant to show when the screen resized using media query

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to fix my responsive navigation bar. supposed to be, when the screen is resized  smaller, the navigation will change to a single button which is "menu" and when clicked, it will toggle the navigation vertically. the problem is, even at full screen size, the menu still shows up. this should only appear when screen was changed. thank you

```
    HTML:
   <div class="nav">
     <ul>
    <li ><a class="active" href="index.php"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="">About us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="site_profile.php">Company Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li ><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    <li ><a href="">Careers</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Blog</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Success Story</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class="contact"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="handle"> Menu </div>
</div>

  CSS:

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding-left: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
 transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
 background-color: #aaa;
 color: #444;
 cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
font-size: .8em;
 }

/*******************************************
 MEDIA
********************************************/
.handle.hidden {
 width: 100%;
 background: white;
 text-align: left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 display: none;
 }  

 @media screen and (min-width: 650px) {

.nav li {
 width: 130px;
 border-bottom: none;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -4px;
   }

.showing { max-height: 20em; }

 .nav a {
  border-bottom: none;
  }

 .nav > ul > li {
  text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
  }

 .nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
  }

 .nav li ul li {
 display: block;
 }
.handle{
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 }
 }

 SCRIPT:
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code you would need to add the class `.hidden` dinamically to the `.menu` html element which is not very convenient but there is a simpler way to make the menu disappear. Just try:

```css
.handle { /* now we don't use the .hidden class */
      width: 100%;
      background: white;
      text-align: left;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
      display: block;
 }  

...

/* inside media query */
 @media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
   .handle {
       display: none; /* this hides the menu on bigger screens */
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
 }
```

Comment: i removed the .hidden on handle class but still "menu" shows on web full  screen size. if i changed the display to none in media query. "menu" no longer shows even on small or large screen size.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The `.handle` code outside the media query (small screen) is the one that should have `display: block`. I changed my answer to reflect that

Comment: you mean display:none inside the media query , and display: block outside? i've tried it but the "menu" no longer visible on large or small screen. OMG help me :'( i've been trying to fix this since yesterday.

Comment: "display: block"  inside the media query will trigger the class .handle "display: none" to show when the screen is resized to smaller. but this isn't working :(

Comment: @gracia I think I found the issue! The `color: white` and `background: white` of the `.handle` are making the menu "invisible" on small screens. check this codepen where I changed the colors and seems to work fine http://codepen.io/wilman/pen/Wwwppv

Comment: @gracia Glad to hear that! Consider accepting my answer :) I'm happy to help in case you have any other question. Cheers!